# Как извлечь количество товаров из разнообразных строк?

Tags: python, парсер, pandas, текст, анализ-данных

Подскажите, как извлечь количество товаров из данного DataFrame:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({
'text':
['полуприцеп-тяжеловоз тсп 94165-0000010 новый 5 шт.; полуприцеп-тяжеловоз тсп 94183-0000010 новый 6шт.',
 'транспортное средство uaz patriot 2017 г.в. комплектация оптимум с дополнительным оборудованием - дополнительный отопитель салона ebespeher 1 шт. - защита ркпп и мкпп уаз 1 единица. - комплект ковриков в салон 1 шт. - коврик в багажник 1 шт. - самоблок. задний дифференциал',
 'неводо-выборочная машина в комплекте с дополнительными изделиями в кол-ве 2-х штук',
 'машина для приготовления горячих напитков larhea bl ec e3 r1 (8 шт.)',
 'комплект печатных форм для полиграфической машины drent vision (8единиц)',
 'блок питания cisco asr 9000 series 750w ac power supply for asr-9001 -2 шт',
 'автомобили уаз - 390945(2 штуки)',
 'устройство выворотки step 2 в количестве 2 (два) шт.',
 'specpricep 994274 2018г.(прицеп)-1 шт.'
 ]})
```

, а в местах, где более одного товара, можно через запятую в лист или строку.

Результат может выглядеть одним из вариантов, либо похожим:

```
pd.DataFrame({'a': [[5,6],[1,1,1,1],[2],[8],[8],[2],[2],[2]],
'b': [[5,6],[1,1,1,1],2,8,8,2,2,2],
'c': ['5,6','1,1,1,1','2','8','8','2','2','2']})
```

Можно простой вариант, если не получится с двумя значениями, парсить последнее и получить:

```
pd.DataFrame({'a': [6,1,2,8,8,2,2,2]})
```

Comment: Через Regexp, но вообще запаритесь, судя по вариантам

Comment: можете показать в вопросе как должен выглядеть результат для приведенного фрейма

Comment: Максим, обновил вопрос.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
pat = r"(\d+)(?:\D+)?(?:шт|ед)"
res = df["text"].str.extractall(pat).groupby(level=0)[0].apply(list)
```

результат:

```
In [51]: res
Out[51]:
0          [5, 6]
1    [1, 1, 1, 1]
2             [2]
3             [8]
4             [8]
5             [2]
6             [2]
7             [2]
8             [1]
Name: 0, dtype: object
```

Для приведенного примера все варианты количества товаров спарсились корректно.

PS в ожидаемом результате отсутствуют данные для последней строки с `"(прицеп)-1 шт."`

Comment: божественно! спасибо! как всегда великолепный код)